# replace surrounding of xy location with NaN

Tags: matlab, replace, buffer

I have a matrix (A) where a certain position (loc) is given by row and column. I would like to "buffer" around this exact position (loc) . So,around the exact position (loc)- defined by one row and one column - the values should be replaced by NaN. So a window of 4x4 is created within the matrix (A) around the loc. How can I do that?

This matrix (A) is used in a loop - during this loop I find each time a certain position (loc) which should be different to the previous position(loc) and not close to the previous position - for that I would like to replace the loc and the "surrounding" of the previous run.

So in the end I have several 'loc' in matrix (A).

I hope I could make myself clear what I would like to do....

I have the impression that the buffer command of Matlab is not suitable in that case. I would rather have to do a loop?

Any suggestions are really appreciated...

Thank you!

Eva

Comment: "window of 4 x 4" can't be centered around a matrix index.  e.g. if your `loc` is `10,10`, would your 4 x 4 be `8:11,8:11` or `9:12,9:12`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the image processing toolbox, and if you use odd-sized "buffers", it's really easy:

```
nBuf = 3; % size of buffer zone. 3 makes a 3-by-3 array centered on the location

mask = false(sizeOfA);

idx = sub2ind(sizeOfA,loc(:,1),loc(:,2));

mask(idx) = true;

mask = imdilate(mask,true(nBuf));
mask(idx) = false;

% now you can use mask to replace all values around the locations with NaN
A(mask) = NaN;
```